# Adding Custom Light/Dark Mode Toggle Buttons for Wordpress: Why does the Code work just fine in Codepen but not in WP; i.e. Clicking is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, darkmode

Briefly: I want to add these buttons to my Wordpress website for a user to toggle either Light or Dark-Mode.
I have written the code separately as a [Codepen item which you can find here](https://codepen.io/LenardG/pen/mdGvrxe); though it works fine there, I can't seem to be able to properly integrate this code into my website.

Just so you know, this is only my second real experience with implementing HTML, CSS, and JS together, and my first with managing code in Wordpress; apologies in advance if I've been overlooking something obvious :-)

[Buttons as they look on the website but clicking either does nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSalo.png)

[Where the Buttons are added in "body"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLmco.png)

[Format using the WP Site Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mdc3.png)

## HTML

```
<!-- 
All that I changed with these two, here, was add id="". The rest is all Wordpress...

The First Button within the Header, using the Wordpress Site Editor, "Edit as HTML" -->

<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-font-size has-small-font-size" id="dark-mode-off"><a class="wp-block-button__link wp-element-button" style="border-radius:100px;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px">      </a></div>

<!-- The Second Button -->

<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-font-size has-small-font-size" id="dark-mode-on"><a class="wp-block-button__link wp-element-button" style="border-radius:100px;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px">      </a></div>
```

## CSS

```
.wp-block-button {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

#dark-mode-on {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

#dark-mode-off {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

## JS

```
const darkModeOnButton = document.getElementById('dark-mode-on');
const darkModeOffButton = document.getElementById('dark-mode-off');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

darkModeOnButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkModeOnButton.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  darkModeOnButton.style.borderColor = 'white';
  darkModeOffButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  darkModeOffButton.style.borderColor = 'white';
  body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
});

darkModeOffButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkModeOnButton.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  darkModeOnButton.style.borderColor = 'black';
  darkModeOffButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  darkModeOffButton.style.borderColor = 'black';
  body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  
  darkModeOffButton.disabled = false;
  darkModeOnButton.disabled = false;
});
```

Some more info:

- To add my custom code, I am using the "[Simple Custom CSS and JS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/#description)" plugin; each part is linked internally.

[Where the CSS and JS are added in "head"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hojJ.png)

- I have two class=".wp-block-button" elements that I added to the header element of my site using the Wordpress Site-Editor; both of which I have styled in CSS, using this plugin.
  With the current code, when one is clicked, it is supposed to change the style of both buttons as well as the background colour. This seems to work correctly in Codepen, but won't respond in Wordpress for whatever reason. The initial CSS appears to apply correctly, but clicking on either button does nothing.

What I tried:

I tried inserting parts of the code in different places within the HTML, in part using the Google "Inspect" tool.
I also tried looking for other "Dark-Mode" step-by-step solutions, and some other similarly worded questions here on stackoverflow, but nothing I have tried so far really helped; I feel like I am missing something fundamental...

(Grasping at straws, could the issue be that I have not enqueued the Javascript file into my functions.php; or generally have something to do with my Website's current version of PHP?
Should I empty my browser cache?

I have been somewhat hesitant to go into and edit my theme files themselves, and was hoping that the plugin would work well enough...)

I am at a loss; I don't know where the issue is. Again, clicking either button does nothing, the initial CSS seems to style correctly, and it works just fine in CodePen.
Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you. =)

Comment: I would add a log in the event listener, so as to see if the function is being triggered. If the event is triggered, I would check to see if another css style is taking priority on the page. It may very well be that what you see as your background is not the body tag, which is being changed. If you're interested I'd be happy to look a little closer with you, though it's difficult for me personally to debug in this format. I appreciate the effort you put into making a well formatted post though!

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or what. Both buttons are having same id "dark-mode-on"?

Comment: You need to debug your code and inspect how it behaves in the browser. Also i would suggest to toggle classes instead of changing styles directly. Check if css is getting overriden

Comment: @asyncawait thank you! I added some console.log("") at various places; none of which were ever reached, as I kept getting this error: "cannot read properties of null reading ('addeventlistener')", right after the first =>{...
This got me thinking about the right question though, and I've solved it now!

Comment: @CodeThing Thanks! Yeah, that's a typo. The two buttons each have the correct "id", when copying the code over from the Site editor, I must have just copied the code from the same block twice.

Comment: @CodeThing While I did find the issue and solved it, I took your advice and made an improved/ more "neat" version taking all that styling back to CSS. Thanks again! https://codepen.io/LenardG/pen/MWqRaRa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Google Inspect Tool Console to debug
it turns out that the fix for me, in this case, was indeed rather simple:

From the TypeError: cannot read properties of null reading ('addeventlistener'), I figured that my constants didn't exist yet; i.e. there were no elements to .getElementId("dark-mode-on") or "...-off)" from.

I had added the JS as "linked internally"(1) and placed it in the "head",
which meant that looking at the (index) file of my Website, the "script" was executed before the "body" tag: executing the code where the IDd elements still had to be read.

My fix for this was to "link externally"(2) and load it using the plugin via a new HTML file, so that it is added in the "footer"(3); after the IDd elements were created.

Now it works perfectly fine :)

In my JS file, I also added

```js
 window.onload=function(){/*Add my Code here*/}
```

before changing those settings, and I am not sure whether this is now redundant... But I'll leave it as is for now.

Updated CodePen: codepen.io/LenardG/pen/MWqRaRa

(1) [PNG Old Settings JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcIVH.png)

(2) [PNG New Settings JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLV5M.png)

(3) [PNG New HTML file Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z76Q.png)